# javascript click function does not work properly in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, click

I started a video project. I wrote my video player myself. I'm using javascript, jquery, asp.net and c #.

I made the video stop in seconds that the user set and the user asked questions to come to the screen. The video stops. The question is coming. Clicking an answer option. The clicked option is saved in the database (for analysis).

I send my data to the server side via ajax. It works perfectly when you answer questions instantly.I bring my questions to the screen with the css I created with Z-index.

Chrome, Edge and Android waiting for a certain period of time I encounter this problem.

My project is not working properly on ios. It brings the first question to the screen 3-4 times. But it makes the other questions show in one click.another questions bring to screen not problem. I just have a problem with the first question on ios. I can't understand why the question comes to the screen 3-4 times.

Html Code

```
<div id="v_area">
    <div id="my_ad">

        <p>
            <div class='clickable-div-1' id="div1">
                <button id="c1"></button>
            </div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class='clickable-div-2' id="div2">
                <button id="c2"></button>
            </div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class='clickable-div-3' id="div3">
                <button id="c3"></button>
            </div>
        </p>
        <p>
            <div class='clickable-div-4' id="div4">
                <button id="c4"></button>
            </div>
        </p>

    </div>
</div>
```

javascript code

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickable-div-1', function() {

v.currentTime += 0.03;
document.getElementById("my_ad").style.visibility = "hidden";

var user = {};

user.Cevap1 = document.getElementById('c1').innerHTML;
var VKodu = document.getElementById('VKodu').innerHTML;
var SoruKodu = document.getElementById('SoruKodu').innerHTML;

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        `
        url: "VideoPlayerDemo.aspx/SonucKaydet", 
 data:'{user:'+JSON.stringfy(user)+',VKodu:'+JSON.stringfy(VKodu)+',SoruKodu:'+JSON.stringfy(user)+'}',

        contenttype:"json",
        success:function(data){        
                    if(document.getElementById("my_ad").style.visibility!="hidden")
{
  document.getElementById("my_ad").style.visibility ="hidden";`
    }

},
}),
}),
v.play();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some apple products block virtual click events like the click event and e.t.c.

Comment: Don't waste your time and force. I'd tried and got unsuccessful result always.

Comment: Isn't there an alternative to the click function? In fact, my project is not very much failed. It works fine except for the first question. Even if you have ios, you can try it at the following link: takip.bizebildir.net/videoplayerdemo.aspx

Comment: You can try play video by javascript YouTube API or Vimeo API. I tested it on iphone and other devices. Success range about 80%. Please, you shouldn't change src via javascript like in common solutions. It doesn't help.@Sebnem Demircioglu